# How to Make Iterator for do sum of a field from n number of objects

Tags: python, django

Lets say i have a model

```
class Testmodel():
   amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   contact = models.CharField()
```

Now I am making a query like:

```
obj1 = Testmodel.objects.filter(contact = 123)
```

and suppose its returning `n` number objects in any case like `(obj1,obj2,obj3 ...)`

So, if I want to make the sum of `amount` from all the returning object `(obj1,obj2,obj3 ...)` then  how to do by the best way.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually better to do this at the database level, than in Python. We can use `.aggregate(..)` for that:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Testmodel.objects.filter(contact=123).aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))['total']
```

The `.aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))` will return a dictionary that contains a single key-value pair: `'total'` will be associated with the sum of the `amount` of the rows. In case no rows are selected (i.e. the filter does not match anything), then it will associate `None` with the key.

Given the database supports to sum up values (most databases do), you construct a query that is something similar to:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total
FROM app_testmodel
WHERE contact = 123
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Testmodel.objects.filter(contact=123).aggregate(
        total_sum=Sum('amount')
)
```